# How to walk through a collection with pagination

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line

I working on a command line which is fetching all the products in the database, using the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` object.

In order to avoid memory problems, I'm going to process the data in chunks, so using the methods `setPageSize` and `setCurPage` to fetch just a portion of the whole dataset and walking through it.

I notice, perhaps the `setCurPage` value passed was increasing, the data returned are the same all the times.
Is there any method I need to call in order to clear the Collection cache if any? Or is there a better way to walk and process the data from the collection?

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;                                        
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;               
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;                               

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory; 
use Magento\Framework\App\State;                     
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;                                                                                                               

class ExportProducts extends Command                 
{                                                  
    public function __construct(                         
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,                                      
        State $state                                                          
    ) {                                                
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->state = $state;

        parent::__construct();                                   
    }                                  

    protected function configure()             
    {  
         // Command description
    } 

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {                    
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_GLOBAL);

        $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $productsQty = $productCollection->getSize();  

        $pageSize = 25;                                      
        $break = false;                              
        $page = 1;                                                                       
        $count = null;
        $lPage = null;   

        while ($break !== true) {                                               
            $productCollection                   
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')          
                ->setOrder('entity_id','ASC')      
                ->setPageSize($pageSize)                 
                ->setCurPage($page)                                                
                ->load();                                                     

            $output->writeln($page);                   

            if($count === null) {
                $count = $productCollection->getSize();   
                $lPage = $productCollection->getLastPageNumber();
            }

            if($lPage == $page) {                              
                $break = true;                               
            }                  

            $page++;    

            foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
                $id = $product->getData('entity_id');
                $pr = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
                /** Here I'm working with the data coming from $product and $pr **/
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you need from `$pr` object?

Comment: $product->getData('quantity_and_stock_status'); returns a string with written 1, instead of the quantity of the stock and it it's in stock or not.
So, I'm accessing that data via $pr.

But I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move  `$productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();` inside while loop

update your while code like this

```
while ($break !== true) {
            $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
            $productCollection
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setOrder('entity_id','ASC')
                ->setPageSize($pageSize)
                ->setCurPage($page)
                ->load();


            if($count === null) {
                $count = $productCollection->getSize();
                $lPage = $productCollection->getLastPageNumber();
            }

            if($lPage == $page) {
                $break = true;
            }

            $page++;

            foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
                $id = $product->getData('entity_id');
                /** Here I'm working with the data coming from $product and $pr **/
            }
        }
```